# How to show smart slider only on home page of wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, slider

I am using Astra theme and Smart Slider 3 plugin in WordPress. I used Astra Hooks plugin to show slider on header and it worked but the slider is displayed on all pages.

How do I make slider appear on home page header only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordpress have [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) to deal with these problems.
i have not used astra hooks plugin, instead you can use the snippet below and paste it in your functions.php file of your child theme. replace your slider's shortcode with `[shortcode_of_your_slider]` and you're good to go.

if you want to change the position of slider checkout [astra visual hooks](https://developers.wpastra.com/theme-visual-hooks/) . right now im using the `astra_header_before` you cant change it with what ever you want

```
add_action( 'astra_header_before', 'shalior_display_header_on_front_age' );
function shalior_display_header_on_front_age() {
    if(is_front_page()){
      echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_of_your_slider]');
    }
}
```